# I can't get Basic Authentication to Pass

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication

I have searched the forums here for a while and am still at a loss.  I am doing Basic Authentication with a predefined username and password.

I know that the username and password are correct because I can directly log in.
I have tried passing a "header", "username", "password" and as you see below using "beforeSend".

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://vcc-na10.8x8.com/api/stats/groups.xml",
  datatype: "xml",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); },
  error: function (){
    alert('cant connect'); 
  },
  success: function (){
    alert('connected'); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you run the two requests through a debugging proxy (eg: Fiddler3) to see how they look different? I suspect the difference between the working and non-working request will be fairly easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the headers parameter to pass authentication. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://vcc-na10.8x8.com/api/stats/groups.xml",
    datatype: "xml",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('cant connect');
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('connected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the username and password directly in the ajax config.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  username: username,
  password: password,
...
```